# Access popup window element JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery

I have written the following code to load a popup(**List B** NewForm.aspx) when a **List A** NewForm.aspx is submitted. The popup has a div.

```
var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
dialogOptions.url = "someURL";
dialogOptions.width = 750;
dialogOptions.height = 500; 
dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate( null, CloseCallback); 
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions);
```

In the **List B** NewForm.aspx, I have added script to access the div. But by following code part div cannot be accessed. Any suggestions please.

```
document.getElementById("divID");
```

Comment: you are trying to access div in which page List A NewForm.aspx or List B NewForm.aspx  ??

Comment: document.getElementById("divID") is added in List B NewForm.aspx

Comment: divID is in List A NewForm.aspx or List B NewForm.aspx ??

Comment: It's also in List B NewForm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1. Check whether you have added all necessary js references in your  List B NewForm.aspx
2. On page load of List B NewForm.aspx, add an alert('Page loaded'), and see whether this loads, if this works, then you might be referencing a wrong div or div which is not available in List B NewForm.aspx.